# django select rows by max value of field

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a table in django like this:

```
class Observation:
    plant = model.ForeignKey
    Trait = model.ForeignKey
    value = model.CharField
    creation_time = model.DateTimeField
```

I want to make a query to get only the newest rows with unique plant/trait combination. Ex:

```
row1 plant1 trait1 value1 dateyesterday
row2 plant1 trait1 value3 datetoday
row3 plant1 trait2 value1 datetoday
```

The query should return only row2 and row3

I have resolved it in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM vavilov_observation AS o
WHERE o.creation_time = (SELECT MAX(creation_time)
                         FROM vavilov_observation AS o2
                         WHERE o.plant_id=o2.plant_id AND o.trait_id=o2.trait_id)
```

Someone can help me transforming this SQL into a django queryset?

Until now The only solution I have found is to make a raw queryset with this sql to get pks from and use them in a Observations.objects.filter(observation_id__in=rawquery_ids) query.

This method is not well scalable. In one of the databases I have 500.000 rows and it takes too long to use in production.

Any help?

Thanks in advance
peio

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
variable = observation.objects.filter(creation_time__gt=now).values('plant', 'trait', 'creation_time')
```

Comment: This is now I am asking.

Comment: I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: Sorry Zorpho, I was writing from the phone. What I meant  is  that your solution is not what I was asking for. Thanks anyway